# WebKit box reflect not working on images on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, webkit

I have noticed that -webkit-box-reflect doesn't seem to work on  elements on iOS Safari.

Basically I have two elements using the reflection - h2 and img. It displays fine on the h2, but the img reflection just doesn't appear. I've tested on both the device and iPhone Simulator. Is there anything that could fix it or it's just a rendering issue on the iPhone?

```
-webkit-box-reflect: below -4px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)));
```

Comment: Same problem.  I'm noting that in XCode's source code editor for my CSS file that it does not highlight the -webkit-box-reflect bit, seems like it doesn't recognize it.